# Get JSON with angular ActivatedRouter snapshot params

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to pull information from JSON remote with ActivatedRouter snapshot params, here is my code:

menu component:

```
   <ul>
                      <li><a routerLink="/home">Home</a></li>
                      <li><a routerLink="/facts/math">Math fact</a></li>
                      <li><a routerLink="/facts/trivia">Trivia fact</a></li>
                      <li><a routerLink="/facts/year">Year fact</a></li>
                      <li><a routerLink="/facts/date">Date fact</a></li>
                </ul>
```

facts component:

```
export class FactsComponent implements OnInit {
    public fact : FactModel ;
    public pathUrl : string;
  constructor(private activatedRouter:ActivatedRoute,
                private factsService : FactsService,
                private elementRef: ElementRef
                ) { }
  async ngOnInit() {
     this.pathUrl = this.activatedRouter.snapshot.params.pathUrl;
      try {
       this.fact = await this.factsService.getFactsAsync("http://numbersapi.com/random/"+this.pathUrl+"?json");
     }
      catch(err) {
          console.log(err.message);
      }
    }
}
```

app-routing module:

```
const routes: Routes = [

    { path: "home", component: HomeComponent },
    { path: "facts/:pathUrl", component: FactsComponent },

];
```

facts service:

```
export class FactsService {

    constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient) { }

    public async getFactsAsync(url:string):Promise<FactModel>{
      const observable=this.httpClient.get<FactModel>(url);
      return observable.toPromise();
    }
  }
```

When I switch between the paths in the menu to get a different fact according to the categories, there is no change and the text remains the same and reports an error to me, I used an Elvis operator but it does not help.

Answer (score 0):

**On route parameter change by default angular just updates the URL but not the component.**
So this can be fixed by the following ways.

change the routeReuseStrategy at the component:

```
constructor(private router: Router) { 
  this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false; 
}
```

Or reset the state of the component when the parameter changes:

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
   this.pathUrl = params['pathUrl'];
  // this.fact = await this.factsService.getFactsAsync ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to parameter changes.

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.pathUrl = params['pathUrl'];
});
```